# My rubber fig plant has grown two new leaves recently but both have a mottled camouflage colour to them. It is otherwise healthy and usually great

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, leaves, figs

It usually has shiny green leaves and grows very well in its home. It hasn’t been moved or had anything changed. It’s around 4 years old.

Comment: Hi Sarah, could you post a photo please.